# Google Maps Marker Cluster

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Hi I am trying to add clustering to my google map.  Its been about eight years since I've actually programmed anything so I've reverted to modifying another website due to my lack of knowledge.  I have added the maerkerclusterer.js script to my page, but I have not idea where to parse

`var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);`

though the marker array.  A demo of my code can be found below:

[Google Map](http://bluextreme.net/TEST.html)

Answer (score 0):

Line 115 should be :

```
var len = guests.length;
var markerArray = [];
```

Than, lines 141-142 to:

```
var marker = google.maps.Marker(map, guests[i]);
markerArray.push(marker );

      } 
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray);
```

This should get it to work.

The point of the chnge is to sen the **MarkerClusterer** an array that contains only the markers, nothing else as the core code is other wise confused and throwing errors.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but it doesn't cluster anything.  Is there a way to debug javascript in the browser?

Comment: There are many ways, depending on your broswer, must of them have a built in tool. I looked at your page, there is indeed a JS error. I just looked at your code again, you need to a minor change there, ee th edit of the answer.

Comment: Still no luck.  If I add "new" at line 142 before google.maps.Marker(map, guests[i]); The array will populate my JSON content.  Otherwise, it doesn't pass the content through the array.